# how do you make a cube with a texture mapped, display a different texture inside and outside

Tags: c++, opengl, mapping, textures

how do you make a cube with a texture mapped, display a different texture inside and outside?

By mapping the texture in the cube, I see both from without and from within the cube the same texture and I need to be different textures.

Working with OpenGL 3.3 or higher and C ++.

Answer (score 1):

Render the cube twice, the second time around with a different texture and the opposite `glFrontFace()`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in `gl_FrontFacing` variable in the fragment shader, which allows you to test if the currently rendered triangle is front facing. You can use a different texture depending on this value. The relevant pieces of the fragment shader can look like this:

```
uniform sampler2D FrontTex;
uniform sampler2D BackTex;
in vec2 TexCoord;
out FragColor;

void main() {
    if (gl_FrontFacing) {
        FragColor = texture(FrontTex, TexCoord);
    } else {
        FragColor = texture(BackTex, TexCoord);
    }
}
```

In your C++ code, you bind the two textures to different texture units, and set the sampler uniforms accordingly.

Comment: Your example doesn't work because of non uniform flow control, you need to sample the texture outside the if or use textureGrad. (https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_%28GLSL%29#Non-uniform_flow_control)

Comment: @Jerem I don't think this make the shader illegal, does it? The way I understand it, the only implication is that the gradients may be undefined. First of all, the gradient only matters if mipmapping is enabled, which is not a given in this context. Also, `gl_FrontFacing` has the same value for an entire triangle, so the control flow will not diverge for the fragments in a single triangle. I would have to try it out, but I'm not convinced that it's a real problem.

Comment: You may be right, since gl_FrontFacing is the same for the whole triangle maybe it's uniform. I'll check it out.

Comment: Yes you were right! Uniform flow control is only about uniforms that can vary inside a primitive.